# When constructing a hypothetical sentence, do I have to keep all the tenses in the past?

Tags: tense, backshifting

> If I bought that book, it would be so I **had** something to give to you on
>   your birthday.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct? 
Or would "have" be a better option than "had"?

Answer (score 1):

Before their birthday:

**If I buy that book, I'll have something to give you for your birthday.**

On their birthday:

**If I bought that book, I'd have something to give you for your birthday.**

After their birthday:

**Had I bought that book, I would have had something to give you for your birthday.**

That is the gist, pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a difficult one, and I've had to think about it a while.  Here are some similar sentences:

> I would buy that book because I want to have something for your birthday.
>   The reason that I would buy that book is so that I will have something for your birthday.
>   If I buy that book, it will be so that I have something for your birthday.
>   If I were to buy that book, it would be so that I have something for your birthday.

All of these are ok, and I think yours is too.  I think the reason that there's so much tense flexibility is because the two ideas (buying the book, having something for the birthday) are only loosely connected.  You want something for the birthday.  That's not hypothetical, that's a fact.  You might buy a book, you might not.  That's hypothetical.

Looking a little further into this, I find StoneyB's excellent answer to a similar question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111331/tense-agreement-in-conditional-statements-i-could-do-whatever-i-want-vs-i-c).  As he says, the actual temporal relationships in conditional sentences are ambiguous.  Also, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bconditional%5Dtense%20agreement) is a list of several posts from the ELU site from a search on posts containing "tense agreement" and having the conditional tag.  They should give you some other ideas.